# Generating 2 channel vector in matlab from a sound file

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a sound file and I want to create a 2-channel vector from this file (because I have to use these two vectors `xi` as input to the LTI system shown in the figure).

```
[xi,fs] = audioread('Emphasis_FFT18_48K.wav');
```

How can I do so?

[image: Given system]

Comment: What is the [`size`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) of `xi` after calling `[xi,fs] = audioread('Emphasis_FFT18_48K.wav');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>> Y = audioread('Kurzweil-K2000-Big-Mono-Bass-C1.wav');
>> size(Y)

ans =

      571951           2
```

You an separate channels as follows:

```
>> channel1 = Y(:,1);
>> channel2=Y(:,2);
```

% With this you have two separate vector one for each channel

```
>> audioinfo('Kurzweil-K2000-Big-Mono-Bass-C1.wav')

ans = 

             Filename: '/home/anquegi/learn/matlab/stackoverflow/Kurzweil-K2000-Big-Mono-Bass-C1.wav'
    CompressionMethod: 'Uncompressed'
          NumChannels: 2
           SampleRate: 44100
         TotalSamples: 571951
             Duration: 12.9694
                Title: []
              Comment: []
               Artist: 'freewavesamples.com'
        BitsPerSample: 16
```